# Where trigonometry root $ 2\pi n $ comes from

Tags: trigonometry

I've and expression like:

$$ \tan^2(x) = \frac{1-\cos^3(x)}{1-\sin^3(x)} $$

and i found roots:

$$ x = \pi n + \frac{\pi}{4} $$
$$ x = (-1)^n * arcsin \frac{\sqrt 2 - 1}{\sqrt 2} + \pi n - \frac{\pi}{4}  $$

but there should be one more which equals to $ 2 \pi n $. Where it comes from as i'm having the following expression:
$$ (\sin(x) - \cos(x)) (\sin(x) + \cos(x) + \sin(x)\cos(x)) = 0 $$

From the first multiplier i have the first root, and from the second i have two, but one is below -1 which is not satisfying requirements.

UPD: I only interested in the root of $ 2\pi n $. I want to see how could i get it, not just guessing that it suits.

Comment: How is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ a root?  At $\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\sin$ and $\cos$ are equal.  Thus $\tan^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = 1$.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Exactly because of the reason you mention is that $\;\pi/4\;$ is a root...

Comment: @DonAntonio Wouldn't a root be where $\tan^2(x) = 0$?

Comment: I think part of the problem, and the confusion, is that you call your **solutions** "roots", whereas you do NOT have an equation equalled to zero. True, you can turn your original expression into one equalled to zero, but the name maybe confusing.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Read my past comment...

Comment: @DonAntonio OK.  I just thought the "expression" was a trig identity I did not know and OP was trying to find roots using the new expression for $\tan^2(x)$.

Comment: @Dmitrii  As Joe's comments show, your wording is confusing. Please do make crystal clear what you meant.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Yes may be it's unclear, but i only interested in the root of $ 2\pi n $. I want to see how could i get it , not just guessing that it suits.

Comment: Your formula $\tan^2=\frac{1-\cos^3}{1-\sin^3}$ is wrong. See my answer below. In which function are you interested? In $\tan^2$ or $\frac{1-\cos^3}{1-\sin^3}$? I wrote for both functions how to get the roots.

Comment: So you are **solving** the equation, and you are saying that you can't find the root $2\pi n$ ?

Comment: I found it just guessed that it suits, but i suppose i should have some multiplier equals to zero to expose it.

Comment: You certainly simplified wrongly. Show your work in simplifying the equation and we will point out where had you been wrong.

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee showed the method i followed below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Writing $\sin x=s,\cos x=c$

$$\dfrac{(1-c)(1+c+c^2)}{(1-s)(1+s+s^2)}=\dfrac{(1-c)(1+c)}{(1-s)(1+s)}$$

If $1-s=0\iff s=1,$ both sides are undefined $\implies s\ne1$

If $1-c=0\iff\cos x=1,x=2m\pi$ where $m$ is any integer

Else

$$\dfrac{1+c+c^2}{1+s+s^2}=\dfrac{1+c}{1+s}$$

$$\iff(s-c)(s+c+sc)=0$$

**Method**$\#1:$

Use [Weierstrass Substitution](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/WeierstrassSubstitution.shtml)

**Method**$\#2:$

Squaring & on rearrangement  we get $$\sin^22x-4\sin2x-1=0$$

$$\sin2x=2\pm\sqrt5$$

As for real $x,\sin2x\le1,$  $$\sin2x\ne2+\sqrt5$$

Now discard the extraneous root.

Comment: Yes i solved it using this method, and got 2 roots from it, but now i'm looking for some way of showing that $ 2\pi n $ is also root.

Comment: I can't follow the explanation even on the first line. More details please?

Comment: @Dmitrii $c^2(1-c)$ is 0 for roots of the form $2\pi n$, so you can't safely divide by it.

Comment: @Dmitrii, Please find the updated answer

Comment: @user202729, Please find the updated answer

Comment: This resolved the confusion OP made (although the question is pretty unclear), so +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks, as i got it right i find $ x = 2 \pi n $ when i divide both parts on $ \frac{1-\cos(x)}{1-\sin(x)} $. I missed the fact that one of them could be the root.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$
\tan^2(x)=0\Leftrightarrow \tan(x)=0\Leftrightarrow x=\pi n \text{ for }n\in\mathbb Z.
$$
So you see that your formula is wrong since
$$
\tan^2(\pi)=0\neq 2=\frac{1-(-1)^3}{1-0^3}=\frac{1-\cos^3(\pi)}{1-\sin^3(\pi)}.
$$
The right formula, using $\tan=\frac{\cos}{\sin}$ and $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$, is given by
$$
\tan^2(x)=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=\frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{1-\sin^2(x)}
$$
Now you can also see
$$
\tan^2(x)=0\Leftrightarrow 1-\cos^2(x)=0\Leftrightarrow \cos(x)\in\{-1,1\}\Leftrightarrow x=\pi n\text{ for }n\in\mathbb Z.
$$
But if you are interested in the roots of $f(x):=\frac{1-\cos^3(x)}{1-\sin^3(x)}$ you get
$$
f(x)=0\Leftrightarrow 1-\cos^3(x)=0\Leftrightarrow \cos^3(x)=1\Leftrightarrow \cos(x)=1\Leftrightarrow x=2\pi n\text{ for }n\in\mathbb Z.
$$
Since $1-\sin^3(2\pi n)=1\neq 0$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$ we deduce that $2\pi n$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$ are all roots of $f$.